# How to calculate the average of a Time column in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have an ID column, and a time column. I want to group the IDs by average time.
IDs: 1234, 1234, 5678, 5678
Times: 13:21, 19:55, 14:25, 15:04

```
select ID, 
avg(cast(CONCAT(left(cast(Time as varchar),2),substring(cast(Time as varchar),4,2)) as int)*1.0)
```

It does return a result, but I don't believe the average to be correct as the average time can be outside of normal time constraints (aka the minutes can be > 59).

Comment: `time`, in SQL Server, represents a time within the day, not a timespan; this is why you can't have a value greater than `23:59:59.9999999` (or lower than `00:00:00.000000`). As such you can't get an average as it doesn't make sense to have the average of points in time (it's like having the average date). If you are using `time` to represent a time span, you'll need to convert the value to a numerical data type to represent the number of "ticks", get the average of those (and optionally convert back).

Comment: Also, don't: `cast(<anything> as varchar)` [without specifying the length](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length).

Answer (score 1):

`time` stores a point in time, not a duration. What would you do for a duration longer than a day? You should instead store either the duration in seconds, minutes, what have you, and format it as `hh:mm` etc. when you want to display it. Or better yet, store a start date and end date, which is more complete information, and you can always derive the duration (in whatever format you like) from that.

Anyway, dealing with what you have, and assuming this table and sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.BadChoices
(
  ID int,
  DurationWithWrongType time(0)
);

INSERT dbo.BadChoices(ID, DurationWithWrongType) VALUES
(1234, '13:21'),
(1234, '19:55'),
(5678, '14:25'),
(5678, '15:04');
```

You could I suppose do:

```
SELECT ID, AvgDuration = CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2), 
    AVG(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '00:00', DurationWithWrongType)*1.0))
  FROM dbo.BadChoices
  GROUP BY ID;
```

Output:

| ID | AvgDuration |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | 998.00 |
| 5678 | 884.50 |

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=38872a8c2f359d0043ffa72200887d25)

If you want the display to be `HH:MM`, and you know for sure your durations will always be < 24 hours, you could do:

```
;WITH src AS
(
  SELECT ID, AvgDuration = CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2), 
    AVG(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '00:00', DurationWithWrongType)*1.0))
  FROM dbo.BadChoices
  GROUP BY ID
)
SELECT ID, AvgDuration, 
  AvgDurHHMMSS = CONVERT(time(0), DATEADD(SECOND, AvgDuration*60, '00:00'))
FROM src;
```

Output:

| ID | AvgDuration | AvgDurHHMMSS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 998.00 | 16:38:00 |
| 5678 | 884.50 | 14:44:30 |

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=28a241f3c7e892eba90c1099174501c8)

Answer (score 0):

We have to cast to datetime to be able to cast to float. We can then find the average and cast back to datetime and then back to time.
A second alternative is to convert the time into minutes, get the average and then use dateadd() and cast back to time

> ```
> create table times(
> t time);
> insert into times values
> ('13:21'), 
> ('19:55'), 
> ('14:25'), 
> ('15:04');
> GO
> ```

4 rows affected

> 

> ```
> select 
>   cast(
>   cast(
>   avg(
>   cast(
>   cast(t 
>     as datetime)
>     as float)
>     )
>     as datetime)
>     as time)
> from times
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | (No column name) |
> | :--------------- |
> | 15:41:15         |
> ```

> ```
> select
>   cast(
>   dateadd(second,
>   avg(
>   DateDiff(second,0,t)
>     ),
>     2000-01-01)
>     as time)
> from times
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | (No column name) |
> | :--------------- |
> | 15:41:15         |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=48e2b19bc5b01e5d61758406fa54c365)*

Comment: Why would you choose `float`? Also it may be implied by the question but should also disclaim about durations > 23:59

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand the question deals with values  of data type time do I work with that. I use float because I can't cast time as int. What would you use?

Comment: Decimal because float does weird things, but also convert to datetime and also to float and then back to datetime and then to time is not the most intuitive thing in the world. My solution calculates average without converting to float or decimal except to make sure we don't lose any decimal minutes from the average. Casting a datetime to float may seem natural to you but I think you're in a small group.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand - I agree with you that 2 casts in each direction is not a good solution. I prefer the solution working in minutes, or seconds if more accuracy is required.